# laravel Trying to get property 'id' of non-object error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I was working on another person's code and when I deployed the laravel app the login page works but when I input the testing credentials it spits out this error

```
    Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
    in helpers.php line 159
    at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get property \'id\' of non-object', '/var/www/html/first-project/app/Helpers/helpers.php', 159, array('fields' => object(Collection), 'fieldsValues' => object(Collection), 'htmlFields' => array(), 'startSeparator' => '<div style="flex: 50%;max-width: 50%;padding: 0 4px;" class="column">', 'endSeparator' => '</div>', 'field' => object(CustomField), 'dynamicVars' => array('$RANDOM_VARIABLE$' => 'var15931958241638660037ble', '$FIELD_NAME$' => 'phone', '$DISABLED$' => '', '$REQUIRED$' => '"required" => "required",', '$MODEL_NAME_SNAKE$' => 'user', '$FIELD_VALUE$' => '\'+136 226 5660\'', '$INPUT_ARR_SELECTED$' => '+136 226 5660'), 'gf' => object(GeneratorField), 'value' => object(CustomFieldValue)))
    in helpers.php line 159
```

The actual function referred to is the following

```
function generateCustomField($fields, $fieldsValues = null)
{
    $htmlFields = [];
    $startSeparator = '<div style="flex: 50%;max-width: 50%;padding: 0 4px;" class="column">';
    $endSeparator = '</div>';
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $dynamicVars = [
            '$RANDOM_VARIABLE$' => 'var' . time() . rand() . 'ble',
            '$FIELD_NAME$' => $field->name,
            '$DISABLED$' => $field->disabled === true ? '"disabled" => "disabled",' : '',
            '$REQUIRED$' => $field->required === true ? '"required" => "required",' : '',
            '$MODEL_NAME_SNAKE$' => getOnlyClassName($field->custom_field_model),
            '$FIELD_VALUE$' => 'null',
            '$INPUT_ARR_SELECTED$' => '[]',

        ];
        $gf = new GeneratorField();
        if ($fieldsValues) {
            foreach ($fieldsValues as $value) {
                if ($field->id === $value->customField->id) {
                    $dynamicVars['$INPUT_ARR_SELECTED$'] = $value->value ? $value->value : '[]';
                    $dynamicVars['$FIELD_VALUE$'] = '\'' . addslashes($value->value) . '\'';
                    $gf->validations[] = $value->value;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        // dd($gf->validations);
        $gf->htmlType = $field['type'];
        $gf->htmlValues = $field['values'];
        $gf->dbInput = '';
        if ($field['type'] === 'selects') {
            $gf->htmlType = 'select';
            $gf->dbInput = 'hidden,mtm';
        }
        $fieldTemplate = HTMLFieldGenerator::generateCustomFieldHTML($gf, config('infyom.laravel_generator.templates', 'adminlte-templates'));


        if (!empty($fieldTemplate)) {
            foreach ($dynamicVars as $variable => $value) {
                $fieldTemplate = str_replace($variable, $value, $fieldTemplate);
            }
            $htmlFields[] = $fieldTemplate;
        }
//    dd($fieldTemplate);
    }
    foreach ($htmlFields as $index => $field) {
        if (round(count($htmlFields) / 2) == $index + 1) {
            $htmlFields[$index] = $htmlFields[$index] . "\n" . $endSeparator . "\n" . $startSeparator;
        }
    }
    $htmlFieldsString = implode("\n\n", $htmlFields);
    $htmlFieldsString = $startSeparator . "\n" . $htmlFieldsString . "\n" . $endSeparator;
//    dd($htmlFieldsString);
    $renderedHtml = "";
    try {
        $renderedHtml = render(Blade::compileString($htmlFieldsString));
//        dd($renderedHtml);
    } catch (FatalThrowableError $e) {
    }
    return $renderedHtml;
}
```

its usage is as follows in the controllers. It is used many times in almost all controllers for example in the UserController.php file I think this is the calling method. I am not that well versed in laravel sorry for any noob mistakes in advance.

```
public function profile()
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->findWithoutFail(auth()->id());
        unset($user->password);
        $customFields = false;
        $role = $this->roleRepository->pluck('name', 'name');
        $rolesSelected = $user->getRoleNames()->toArray();
        $customFieldsValues = $user->customFieldsValues()->with('customField')->get();
        $hasCustomField = in_array($this->userRepository->model(), setting('custom_field_models', []));
        if ($hasCustomField) {
            $customFields = $this->customFieldRepository->findByField('custom_field_model', $this->userRepository->model());
            $customFields = generateCustomField($customFields, $customFieldsValues);
        }
        return view('settings.users.profile', compact(['user', 'role', 'rolesSelected', 'customFields', 'customFieldsValues']));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change this line

**From**

```
$user = $this->userRepository->findWithoutFail(auth()->id());
```

**To**

```
$user = $this->userRepository->findWithoutFail(auth()->user()->id());
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess, change this `$user = $this->userRepository->findWithoutFail(auth()->id());` to `$user = $this->userRepository->findWithoutFail(auth()->user()->id);`

Added `auth()->user()->id;`